# Unable to connect to my github.com repo due to error 422 in Heroku

Tags: github, heroku, repository, pipeline

Im At heroku, I enabled / connected to my github.com org, I can see that the 3rd party access is given and OK but at heroku when I want to search for any repo on that Org I see the following message in a red box on the top right side of the screen:

```
Item could not be retrieved:
GET https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=fork%3Atrue+user%3.......: 
422 - Validation Failed Error summary: message: The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them. resource: Search field: q code: invalid // See: https://docs.github.com/v3/search/
```

Any ideas or clues?

Comment: Same problem, Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution on this?